# Rename a file in cmd that has a different name with each update

Tags: cmd, file-rename

I am in the process of automating a system to deliver some software to some of my servers, but one of the files i need to copy has a filename that changes with every version that the author produces for example: "filev1.8.8.jar" and then it would be "filev1.8.9.jar" and so on.  What I want to do is change the file to make it just "file.jar".  Is this possible in cmd?

Thank You.

Comment: You can use symbolic link. For example in process:
unlink(file.jar)
ln -s filev1.8.8.jar file.jar

Or may be you meant something else?

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
SET "filemask=filev*.*.*.jar"
dir /b /a-d /o-d "%sourcedir%\%filemask%"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
   'dir /b /a-d /o-d "%sourcedir%\%filemask%" '
  ) DO COPY /y /b "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%sourcedir%\file.jar" >nul&GOTO done
:done

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

This relies on the required file being the latest matching the mask in the directory.